# Conditional loading of Chrome based on working internet (WLAN) connection

Tags: windows, vba, wsh, windows-embedded

I have a thin client running stand alone on Windows XP embedded which will be used as a information screen. Information shall be pulled from the internet (through a website) when a WLAN-connection has been succesfully established. So what I'm looking for is a way to on Windows launch, check for a working internet connection. If the connection is OK, I want to launch a website from internet in Google Chrome. If no working connection has been found, I want to launch a *local* website in Chrome. In pseudo-code:

```
if (working internet connection)
    launch Chrome with internet
else
    launch Chrome with local website
end
```

Maybe this is possible with a piece of Visual Basic? Or is there some other scripting possible? The script shall run on system startup.

In an advanced version of this script I would eventually like to create a local copy of the website automatically when there is a working connection.

All this because the WLAN connection is quite unrealible in the place where this will be used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This, from Randy Birch's VB.NET site, should do it:

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/internetcheckconnection.htm